# Composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet doesn't work

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I want to write a Script using the package Phpspreadsheet. I am not experience in php. I am trying to add the reference to my script through sudo composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet. But it doesn't work. I am getting the error: In stallation failed, deleting composer.json....If have no idea why it is not working. Any idea?

Detailed Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.0.0].
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: You probably should not be using `sudo`. Typically composer dependencies would be installed in the project space rather than as a superuser.  But if you scroll up in the composer output there should be more information. I just tried it and got _phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system_  meaning I do not have the zip extension installed. You may have that problem or other similar issues.

Comment: I am using the statement `sudo Composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`

Comment: My point is that you should probably only use `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` without `sudo`. Do so and post the full error output. It should provide more than just "installation failed"

Comment: Yes, I am getting: `failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Okay then you probably don't have write access where you are trying to install this and `sudo` _is_ necessary. So use `sudo` but include the full error output (edit your original post rather than comment).

Comment: I am getting now this error (updated in my question)

Comment: so I am installing ext-dom?

Answer (score 93):

So I should install

`sudo apt install php-xml`

`sudo apt install php7.0-gd`

`sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring`

`sudo apt install php-zip`

Comment: For coherence, `sudo apt install php7.0-xml php7.0-gd php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip`

Comment: has anyone been able to install the zip extension for `php7.2` ? it keep on saying **E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip'** i have tried alot of variations but none work, i have **PHP Version 7.2.17-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+3**

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked well. Since mine was `php7.2` I changed the`php7.0` to `php7.2` and the other two the same. then it worked prefect!

Comment: Better specify php version for every command (`php7.3-xml`, `php7.3-gd`, `php7.3-mbstring`, `php7.3-zip`).

Comment: That commands are solved my problem too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem, i fix it by doing this

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Any explanation ?

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras by using the --ignore-platform-req option, you instruct Composer to skip the platform requirement checks and proceed with the installation regardless of any mismatches.

Comment: it's still not working in my case

Answer (score 15):

also while running composer install/update or install new package adds

```
--ignore-platform-reqs
```

at the end of command, while add/install successfully for different environments.

Answer (score 4):

In Centos:

sudo yum install gd gd-devel php-gd

Answer (score 4):

sudo apt install php-xml

sudo apt install php7.0-gd

sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring

sudo apt install php-zip

Comment: in my case i was missing php7.3-zip, after installing the error disappeared

Answer (score 3):

Please read the error message "requires ext-dom".  It is complaining about a missing package or in this case php extension.  Generally, when you can't install a package you can look at the required packages in its composer.json to see the complete list.

phpoffice (1.1.0 in this case) requires the following:

```
   "require": {
        "php": "^5.6|^7.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-xmlreader": "*",
        "ext-xmlwriter": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-zlib": "*",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0.0",
        "jpgraph/jpgraph": "^4.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "@stable"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

type

```
 php -v
```

if php7 type

```
sudo apt install php-xml
sudo apt install php7.0-gd
sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt install php-zip
```

if php8 type

```
sudo apt install php-xml
sudo apt install php8.0-gd
sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring
sudo apt install php-zip
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message display miss. I had the same problem, fix it by doing this.
Please read the error message "requires ext-dom".

please install php7.1-dom

in my case, PHP is 7.1
below is I did and working now.

> sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-json php7.1-opcache php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-zip php7.1-fpm
>   sudo apt install php-xml  php7.1-gd  php7.1-dom

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I solve it using the command `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

If you are arch user edit `/etc/php74/php.ini` or whichever version you use.
Makes sure the extension is installed and the gd extension is uncommented.

```
extension=gd
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check your system PHP version**

**If your system PHP 8.0 then run the below command**

> sudo apt-get install php8.0-xml php8.0-gd php8.0-mbstring php8.0-zip

**If your system PHP 7.0 then run the below command**

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml php7.0-gd php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip

Answer (score -1):

if you are using

```
$sheet->setAutoFilter();
```

try comment this to test

```
//$sheet->setAutoFilter();
```

works for me

Answer (score -1):

composer require maatwebsite/excel:*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31420062)