# Laravel maatwebsite/excel composer install error in mac

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Trying to install maatwebsite/excel in XAMPP 7.1.32 rev 1  via composer for mac.
How do I enable these extensions in XAMPP for mac or is there any other issue. Please help me.

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.10 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.11 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.12 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.13 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.14 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.15 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.16 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.17 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.7 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.8 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.9 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.0 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.1 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.2 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.3 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.4 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.5 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.6 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.8.2 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.8.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.8.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.7.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.6.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.5.2 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.5.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.5.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.1.15, 3.1.16, 3.1.17, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9].
```

zip is enabled in my php info.

[image]

Comment: Would you visit if works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240726/composer-require-phpoffice-phpspreadsheet-doesnt-work

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? It's pretty common that the CLI version of PHP and the module for your webserver do **not** share their configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the above solutions don't work, use this

`Yajra/Datatables` Installation Issues
`phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.`

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3 --force
```

Answer (score 22):

When you run composer from the command line it's unlikely you're using the same version of PHP that XAMPP is using to run your website, which is likely why it's reporting the missing zip issue here.

The simplest fix would be to ignore the platform requirements (in this case ext-zip) during the install by running `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`.

Answer (score 13):

Would you please run:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

If `phpspreadsheet` is already installed. Then, upgrade the version in `composer.json`. Just replace existing version with the compatible version.Example, Replace with:
`"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9",`

And run `composer update`

For more details [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Also, check `zip` module via `php -m` if it exists or not for sure. If, you can't find `zip` module there. You have to install it, already your error saying, it does not exist in your system - [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac).

Comment: worked fine.. Need to re install php cli with zip extension.

Comment: Please share more details. As `maatwebsite/excel` requires that package, there should be no need to require it manually. And if the ZIP extension is missing, requiring any package that needs this extensions should still be not working

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem,
I am using Laravel 9.

Try this `composer require maatwebsite/excel --with-all-dependencies` this solve the problem.

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks Oscar

"composer require maatwebsite/excel --with-all-dependencies"

Answer (score 4):

the "extension=gd" was commented in php.ini, You just that line Out of Comment and problem was solved!!!

Comment: `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 requires ext-zip` - that won't be resolved by enabling the gd extension

Answer (score 2):

i just ran the following command and it worked for me .

As i have php 7.3 installed on my ubuntu system , so i ran this command .

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that **phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^ 1.6** is needed

Add to `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9"
    },
```

After, Run this command in the command prompt: `composer update`

**OR**

To install the most recent version [phpoffice/phpspreadsheet](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet), run the following command

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

More info: [phpoffice/phpspreadsheet](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet) | [maatwebsite/excel](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel)

Comment: This error was because php cli version was missing zip extension.

Comment: Please share more details. As `maatwebsite/excel` requires that package, there should be no need to require it manually. And if the ZIP extension is missing, requiring any package that needs this extensions should still be not working

Answer (score 1):

first,
remove the `;`  from `;extension=gd` in php.ini .
then, execute
`composer require psr/simple-cache ^2.0` to change your cache.

then install maatwebsite/excel :
`composer require maatwebsite/excel`