# installing maatwebsite/excel with laravel 9 but getting the phpoffice/phpspreadsheet errors

Tags: laravel, composer-php, maatwebsite-excel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

installing maatwebsite/excel with Laravel 9 but getting phpoffice and PHP version issues. I am using PHP 8.1, I downgrade to PHP 8.0 but still doesn't work. Even I enable the gd extention from the php.ini file.

I am installing maatwebsite using below command which is offered by official website

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel maatwebsite/excel composer install error in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335105/laravel-maatwebsite-excel-composer-install-error-in-mac)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem it's happening due to cache problem, we need to update the cache version.

Let me explain it with all steps

1. Go to the php.ini file and remove ;

before

```
;extension=gd
```

after

```
extension=gd
```

2. execute the command to change your cache

```
composer require psr/simple-cache ^2.0
```

if the above version is not work for you try it with 1.0 version (optional)

```
composer require psr/simple-cache ^1.0
```

Then install maatwebsiteexcel

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

It will work like a charm

Comment: Thanks. Organize answer, it work like a charm what you say.

Answer (score 5):

This will help you

```
composer require psr/simple-cache:^1.0 maatwebsite/excel
```

Some time composer require fails on Laravel 9 because of the simple-cache dependency, you will have to specify the psr/simple-cache version as ^1.0 in your composer.json to satisfy the PhpSpreadsheet dependency.

**find solution here https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html**

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Requiring these two packages has already been recommended in the other answer, so what's the point in duplicating that other answer?

Comment: sure, as I found this statement in given link that 
Some time composer require fails on Laravel 9 because of the simple-cache dependency, you will have to specify the psr/simple-cache version as ^1.0 in your composer.json to satisfy the PhpSpreadsheet dependency.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Answer (score -1):

if anyone still have the same problem then uncomment extension=zip and extension=gd in your php.ini

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers

Comment: i did not duplicate anything